# Iteratively multiply elements of two lists in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, multiplication

I have two lists (`X` and `Y`). I want to first scale the first element of `X` with all the elements of `Y` before moving to the second element of `X` which is then again scaled by all the elements of `Y`. How can I do this? Ideally, I would also like to append it to different lists (`L`) when a new element of X is started, but I am not sure if that is possible.

```
Y = [2, 3, 4, 5]
X = [1, 2, 3, 4]
L = []
for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(len(Y)):
        X_scale = X[i] * Y[j]
        L.append(X_scale)
```

Preferred outcome:

```
# First element in X
X_scale = [2, 2, 3, 4]
X_scale = [3, 2, 3, 4]
X_scale = [4, 2, 3, 4]
X_scale = [5, 2, 3, 4]

# Second element in X
X_scale = [1, 4, 3, 4]
X_scale = [1, 6, 3, 4]
#etc
```

Comment: Do you want the outer product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to follow your pattern:

```py
Y = [2, 3, 4, 5]
X = [1, 2, 3, 4]
L = []
for i,x in enumerate(X):
    for y in Y:
        X_scale = X.copy()
        X_scale[i] = x * y
        L.append(X_scale)

for row in L:
    print(row)
```

Output:

```py
[2, 2, 3, 4]
[3, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 4, 3, 4]
[1, 6, 3, 4]
[1, 8, 3, 4]
[1, 10, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 6, 4]
[1, 2, 9, 4]
[1, 2, 12, 4]
[1, 2, 15, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 12]
[1, 2, 3, 16]
[1, 2, 3, 20]
```

Per OP's comment to group the indices:

```py
Y = [2, 3, 4, 5]
X = [1, 2, 3, 4]
L = []
for i,x in enumerate(X):
    L2 = []
    for y in Y:
        X_scale = X.copy()
        X_scale[i] = x * y
        L2.append(X_scale)
    L.append(L2)

for row in L:
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 3, 4], [4, 2, 3, 4], [5, 2, 3, 4]]
[[1, 4, 3, 4], [1, 6, 3, 4], [1, 8, 3, 4], [1, 10, 3, 4]]
[[1, 2, 6, 4], [1, 2, 9, 4], [1, 2, 12, 4], [1, 2, 15, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3, 8], [1, 2, 3, 12], [1, 2, 3, 16], [1, 2, 3, 20]]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there also a way to save the first 4 lists in another variable or that we at least know which indexes belong to the first element of X and second element of X etc. A bit like in the preferred outcome.

Comment: @JonnDough Sure, just make sublists.  See edit.

Answer (score 0):

First you can simply you loops by accessing the items directly, without an index. Then you can transform the inner loop into a comprehension list to make it more compact:

```py
Y = [2, 3, 4, 5]
X = [1, 2, 3, 4]
L = []
for x_item in X:
    L += [x_item * y_item for y_item in Y]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Although the multiplication is correction, it is not the intended outcome as shown in the question. I would like to append the lists to L.